# Puzzle in R with for loops

Tags: java, r

I have the following task to solve: I have 100 doors in a row from 1-100. I send 10 persons into the row of doors one after another. The doors are initially opened. 
first person opens every 5-th door;; 5, 10, 15, 20...100
second person opens every 10-th door; 10, 20, 30 40, 100
third person opens every 15-th door; 15,30 45... 100
This pattern continues until the last person opens door nr: 50 and 100 (50-th doors).

which doors are closed after everyone have passed? It should output the specific number of doors, (example, 5,70,75,96,100).

I have solved the issue in Java with the my code displayed underneath. I am now trying to solve it in R, but I have problems with the for loops, I'm not getting the correct answer (I must use for loop statements). Anyone have some suggestions how to solve it?

```
enter code here

int personer = 10;
        boolean[] doorOpen = new boolean [100];
        int startPosition;

for(int start = 5; start < 51; start +=5) {


            for(int i = start-1; i < doorOpen.length;  i = i + start) {

                if ( doorOpen [i] == false ) {
                    doorOpen[i] = true;
                    //System.out.println("endret d¯r nr: " + (i+1) + "  --------  " +" D¯r lukket : " + doorOpen[i] );

                } else {
                    doorOpen[i] = false;
                    //System.out.println("endret d¯r nr: " + (i+1) + "  --------  " +" D¯r lukket : " + doorOpen[i] );
                }
            }
            System.out.println();


        } 
for (int i = 0; i < doorOpen.length; i++) {

             if(doorOpen[i] == true) {
                 System.out.print((i+1) + "  ");
             }
         }  

    } // main slutt
```

My R code starts as follow:

```
enter code here


door_game <- function(total_doors=100,passes=10) {
doors <- rep(FALSE,total_doors)

for ....


return (which(doors==true))

door_game()
```

Comment: "but I have problems with the for loops" => What problems exactly?

Comment: I dont know how to create it. I only know how to create it if its jumps with 1 door. In this case its 5. I have limited experience in R.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the outer operator to calculate which doors each person would open, if they were not limited to 100 doors. (Think multiplication table)

```
no_limit <- seq(5,50,5) %o% 1:20
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
 [1,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50    55    60    65    70    75    80    85    90    95   100
 [2,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100   110   120   130   140   150   160   170   180   190   200
 [3,]   15   30   45   60   75   90  105  120  135   150   165   180   195   210   225   240   255   270   285   300
 [4,]   20   40   60   80  100  120  140  160  180   200   220   240   260   280   300   320   340   360   380   400
 [5,]   25   50   75  100  125  150  175  200  225   250   275   300   325   350   375   400   425   450   475   500
 [6,]   30   60   90  120  150  180  210  240  270   300   330   360   390   420   450   480   510   540   570   600
 [7,]   35   70  105  140  175  210  245  280  315   350   385   420   455   490   525   560   595   630   665   700
 [8,]   40   80  120  160  200  240  280  320  360   400   440   480   520   560   600   640   680   720   760   800
 [9,]   45   90  135  180  225  270  315  360  405   450   495   540   585   630   675   720   765   810   855   900
[10,]   50  100  150  200  250  300  350  400  450   500   550   600   650   700   750   800   850   900   950  1000
```

Then you could use the ones that are <= 100 and use setdiff to find the unopened doors. Since all 10 people open doors in multiples of 5, no surprise that all opened are not.

```
setdiff(1:100,no_limit[no_limit<=100])
 [1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 26 27 28 29 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 39 41 42 43 44 46 47 48 49 51 52 53 54 56 57 58 59 61
[50] 62 63 64 66 67 68 69 71 72 73 74 76 77 78 79 81 82 83 84 86 87 88 89 91 92 93 94 96 97 98 99
```

Knowing that all opened doors will be multiple of 5, you could also use the modulo function (`%%`):

```
c(1:100)[1:100%%5!=0]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 26 27 28 29 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 39 41 42 43 44 46 47 48 49 51 52 53 54 56 57 58 59 61
[50] 62 63 64 66 67 68 69 71 72 73 74 76 77 78 79 81 82 83 84 86 87 88 89 91 92 93 94 96 97 98 99
```

Comment: @Meg Loops are not optimal in R. The best solutions are usuallu vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do that with a loop:

```
number_of_persons <- 10
total_doors <- 100
open_doors <- seq(5,number_of_persons*5,5)

opened_result <- NULL
for (i in open_doors){
  opened <- seq(i,total_doors,i)
  opened_result <- unique(c(opened_result,opened))
}

not_opened <- setdiff(1:total_doors,opened_result)
```

Comment: Thank you! If i copy that in, I don't get any answers out. What is missing?

Comment: The data is in the objects that we created. If you type `not_opened` in your console and press go, you should see the unopened doors.

Comment: @Meg Add your expected return to the question. You provided an example desired result but it makes no sense. Door number 5 will be the first opened.

Comment: the correct answer should be: 5, 20, 45, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 85, 90, 95, 100

Comment: @Meg, But person number 2 opens doors #10, why isn't it in there?

Comment: what do you mean?